# Daterangepicker issue when date field showed in popup

Tags: daterangepicker

I have an issue with daterangepicker on a mobile responsive website. My date text field in the popup and when I first click on date text field it was showing daterangepicker calendar but when I choose any date or click on anywhere in this daterangepicker calendar then background pop was closed first. I want that popup will not close and date will select when I click on daterangepicker calendar.

> Please look at this website
>   https://h2otrips.staging.wpengine.com/charter-yacht-search/ .

**Check-in responsive mode and click on right top filter button and then click on select date range and then click on any date it will not select the date and close background popup.**